# Returning Promise { <pending> } for object value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm building a blog and for each blog post I'm trying to include the authors name, rather than the authors ID.

I have two functions: `getUserName` and `mapData`.

mapData remaps the blog object:

```
function mapData(posts) {
    let result = [];
    result = posts.map(post => ({ 
        id: post._id,
        title: post.title,
        imageURL: post.imageURL,
        body: post.body,
        author: getUserName(post.createdBy),
        date: date(post.createdAt) 
    }));
    console.log(result)
    return result;
}
```

getUserName gets the users name:

```
const getUserName = async id => {
    try {
        const getUser = await User.findById(id)
        console.log(getUser)
        return getUser.firstname;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

But after console logging the result in `mapData` the value for `author` is `Promise { <pending> }`. Can anyone explain why this is happening? I thought by using an `async` function would avoid this?

Comment: Why do you have two opening parentheses in the `map` invocation before passing the actual function? Is that a type while you were posting code here or?

Comment: Yep, typo. I'll fix it @MilanVelebit

Answer (score 0):

An async function returns a `Promise`. The easiest thing to do here would be to mark the map cb as async as well and then `await getUserName()`;

As mentioned in the comments this can get a bit messy because you'd be dealing with many more `Promises` afterwards. If you'd rather not deal with that and you're using MongooseJS you could [use Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), for the author field which will simply return the data you need with only one call on your part.

Comment: Tried that but am getting an `Unexpected identifier` error

Comment: Then `result` will be an array of promises. You should probably specify how to deal with that as well.

Comment: Promise.all(result) would be one way. But if one rejects then it all rejects so that's not the cleanest way.

Comment: There's `Promise.allSettled` for that as well